# ASP:RadioButtonList Databind Custom Object

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, radiobuttonlist

Hey guys, I'm having a bit of trouble with my ASP:RadioButtonList, searched Google and SO, no luck, can you help me out?

I'm having trouble databinding. I've got a custom class that looks like this:

```
public class myClass{
  public myInnerClass{
    public int myID;
    public String myTextField;
    /* other fields*/
  }
  public List<myInnerClass> myList;
}
```

And I'm trying to bind a Generic List of it's inner class to a radiolist:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
  myClass data = anotherClass.getData();
  uxRadioList1.DataSource = data.myList;
  uxRadioList1.DataTextField = "myTextField";
  uxRadioList1.DataValueField = "myID";
  uxRadioList1.DataBind();
}
```

But it just won't go. When I don't specify the DataTextField and DataValueField field it binds, but it displays 'myClass+myInnerClass' . How do I do this properly?

Comment: "But it just won't go" isn't too descriptive.  What happens when you do specify the DataTextField and DataValueField?

Comment: Why the nested class? Just remove it and you will have far less problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can only bind to public properties, but not to fields. Try changing the fields of myInnerClass to properties:

```
public class myClass{
  public myInnerClass{
    public int myID { get; set; }
    public String myTextField { get; set; }
    /* other fields*/
  }
  public List<myInnerClass> myList;
}
```